# Using Jquery or Css to set heights or width of a unknown number of elements

Tags: jquery, css

I have a very simple layout of a product Image and an unknown number of alt images to the right of it.

I need a way to set the alt's to have a percent of some sort that makes them all add up to the height of the main image that way I get a even look.

I have tried some simple jQuery but it doesn't seem to be giving me the layout I want.

Here is a link to my fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/r7MgY/7112/

Comment: Is the main image always the same size, or variable?

Comment: The main Image will be will be liquid but it will have a max-width and height of 600px

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your main problem is that you are setting the height of the small images to a % of the container, not the image itself. You can solve this by just setting the height of the big image to 100%, or alternatively calculate the height of the big image / number of elements to get the pixel height of the small images.

Secondly, you are setting the width and not the height on the small images.

Here is an edited version of your script that will help you along:

```
$(function() {
    var altImages =$('div.alt').children('img');
    var altCount = altImages.length;

    var smlHeight = Math.floor($('#big').height() / altCount);
    smlHeight -=2; //account for borders
    smlHeight -=2; //account for padding
    smlHeight -=2; //account for margins

    altImages.css('width',smlHeight + 'px');
    $('.alt').css('width',smlHeight + 'px');
});
```

Notes:

- You will have to add an id to the big image (I assumed id='big')
- You will have to tweak the offsets for borders, padding, and margins. They aren't quite right yet, but with some playing you should be able to get it.

Comment: So I should be setting a percent to the alt images not the div that they are in, I thought i was doing that with .altWrap img { width: 100%; }

Comment: Yes. That too. There are a number of problems. I'm tweaking your fiddle example, will post it in a second.

Comment: Thank you very much John I cant tell you how much it helps

Comment: You know, I'll probably get crucified for this, but have you considered a table layout instead of using jQuery to manipulate the sizes after the fact?

Comment: Yea, I have and yes I too would probally get a bunch of criticism fo it , but are you suggesting that it's not the best approach to use divs ?

Comment: It is best to use divs as much as possible, but it is a lot easier to use tables. Hang on. I have a solution I am posting in a sec.

Comment: For the table approach, just do a 2col/1row table with the big image in the left cell. In the right cell do an embedded table with 1 column and 1 row for each small img. Set the height of all small images to 100%, and don't set the cell heights in the table and it should evenly distribute them.

Comment: John that is awesome approach, going to go ahead and give it a whirl , thanks points for you

Comment: Just to be clear: The div solution (without jQuery) is probably the "Right" solution, but the table solution is going to be a bit more reliable across browsers and much easier to get working.

Comment: I guess I could just apply this approach for percentages to but just adjust my math to get %?

Comment: Well you could. Then you'd need to set the height of the outer div (containing the small images) to match the big image height, then calculate the percentages. You could do it either way.

Comment: You did happen to have time to help me with the liquid version of this?